# Gimp - jagged pencil and brush strokes

Tags: drawing, tablet, gimp, brush, stroke

I am using Gimp 2.8.14 on Ubuntu 14.04 and a Wacom tablet (Intuos 3 6x8).

My problem is that I cannot make a smooth stroke even when I check the **Smooth stroke** in the **Tool Options** panel. When I do that the problem is less evident, but is still there.

I believe the tablet is not the problem because in Krita the problem does not appear.

[image: Example of me trying to write my own name with the pencil tool and a stroke with the brush tool:]

I have already uninstalled Gimp and installed it again and the problem persists.

Can you please give some directions to solve the problem?

Comment: You should ask this at graphicdesign.stackexchange.com - but the sort answer is to simply tweak the "Quality" and "Weight" parameters.

Comment: @jsbueno, thank you for your answer. I am looking at the interface right now and I cannot find those parameters. I have just searched the **Tool Options, Brush Editor, Paint Dynamics Editor and the Preferences window.** Could you please elaborate a little bit more? And yes, I will ask at graphicdesign.stackexchange.com too.

Comment: @jsbueno, I opened Gimp again and found those parameters, but is necessary to put both at the maximum values to have the result expected. The result is a very slow machine. Painting is very difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Michael Schumacher (@MichaelSchumacher) pointed out in his comment at the *Graphic Design* area of this forum (https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/61990/gimp-jagged-pencil-and-brush-strokes?noredirect=1#comment92145_61990), the

**View > Snap to Grid**

option was turned on and, as a result, interfering with the brush strokes.

Just turn it off and everything is OK.

**Do not check the Smooth stroke paramenter** at the **Tool Options panel,** because it will slow down your machine a lot. I tried that and, to have the desired result, I put the values at the maximum levels. I could not paint freely after that.